# move files that match file names in another directory

Tags: command-line, bash

I have two directories:
`dir_1` which has `a.mp4`, `b.mp4`, `c.mp4`, `d.mp4` and `dir_2` which has only `a.txt`, `b.txt`.
The script should move `a.mp4` and `b.mp4` to `dir_3` because only these file names match the file names in `dir_2`.
I find it to hard follow the scripts when I need to do these type of particular operations.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```bsh
for f in "dir_2"/*; do
    filename=${f##*/}
    mv -t "dir_3" "dir_1/${filename%.*}".*
done
```

- Loop files in `dir_2` (use `*.txt` to only loop these files)
- `${f##*/}` gives you the file name without the path.
- `${filename%.*}` gives you the filename without extension.
- `mv -t "dir_3" "dir_1/${filename%.*}".*` moves all files with given `filename` (cleared from the extension) to `dir_3`. You can specify `.mp4` instead of `.*` if you want.